# Questions about parallel testing, need information about Cucumber, Selendroid, and Spoon

Tags: cucumber-jvm, selendroid, spoon

I need to implement a parallel testing feature to my tests, I found these three; Spoon, Cucumber(parallel-cucumber) and Selendroid(Selenium grid). But I searched for some information about them and I couldn't find it anywhere...

Spoon: Do it run in Webviews?

Cucumber: do it work with both UIAutomator and Espresso?

Selendroid: do it also run with UIAutomator and Espresso?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What language are you thinking of? Cucumber is available in quite a few different languages.

Comment: I'm developing my tests in Java for a Android application, I'm using UIAutomator, Espresso, Gradle and Jenkins, and I just need a tool to do test in two devices at the "same time", that don't require me to stop using any of those tools, nothing else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with UIAutomator and Espresso but I am familiar with Cucumber.

The steps you implement in Cucumber are regular Java methods. If you can use UIAutomator or Espresso from regular Java methods, then yes. You are able to use UIAutomator and Espresso with Cucumber-JVM.

Comment: I understood, I wished for a more specific answer but since my question isn't specific at all, I can't complain!